# query string to array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Query String

```
    name=form1

    &settings={"en":{"name":"Form 1","classes":["leftAlign"],"heading":"h2","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[1,0,0]}},"styles":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"}}

    &fields[0].id=null&fields[0].name=password1&fields[0].type=Password&fields[0].settings={"en":{"label":"Password 1","value":"","description":"","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[0,0,0]}},"_persistable":true,"required":true,"restriction":"no","styles":{"label":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"value":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"description":{"color":"777777","backgroundColor":"default"}}}&fields[0].sequence=0&fields[0].status=

........
```

i need to convert this into array output. i used few method to parse the querystring to array. this is the output i got. but the array 'Fields' values are not showing. is there any other way to get that? field[0], fields[1] & fields[2] has key & values but not showing.

```
Array
(
    [name] => form1
    [settings] => {"en":{"name":"Form 1","classes":["leftAlign"],"heading":"h2","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[1,0,0]}},"styles":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"}}
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [create] => Create
)
```

Comment: i just printed $_GET, i got this output. meanwhile i used   echo $str = urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);  // get query srting 

 $s = parseQueryString($str);
 
    //Function 
 function parseQueryString($str) { 
  $op = array(); 
  $pairs = explode("&", $str); 
  foreach ($pairs as $pair) { 
   list($k, $v) = array_map("urldecode", explode("=", $pair)); 
   $op[$k] = $v; 
  } 
  return $op; 
 } 

reset($s);

while (list($key, $value) = each($s)) {
     "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}

Comment: @knightrider kindly give some guidance

Comment: you mean print_r function right?; have you tired to access it via $_GET['id']; is it printed then?

Comment: this code below will print all the parameters and values. I hope since you just want to parse data this should be enough <?php
$a = explode('&', $QUERY_STRING);
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($a)) {
    $b = split('=', $a[$i]);
    echo 'Value for parameter ', htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[0])),
         ' is ', htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[1])), "<br />\n";
    $i++;
}
?>

Comment: Did the previous solution work for you?

Comment: I'm getting. is that possible to group those as fields[0] , fields[1]. etc..

Comment: @Parthi04 try to use fileds[]

Comment: just create an array out of it (instead of echo add each element to fild[] array)

Comment: Have you tried using the HttpQueryString class? However, I'm not sure  your `fields[0].id` syntax is a standard format recognized by PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Code**

```
$query = 'name=form1'
        . '&settings={"en":{"name":"Form 1","classes":["leftAlign"],"heading":"h2","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[1,0,0]}},"styles":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"}}'
        . '&fields[0].id=null&fields[0].name=password1&fields[0].type=Password&fields[0].settings={"en":{"label":"Password 1","value":"","description":"","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[0,0,0]}},"_persistable":true,"required":true,"restriction":"no","styles":{"label":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"value":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"description":{"color":"777777","backgroundColor":"default"}}}&fields[0].sequence=0&fields[0].status='
        //adding fields[1]
        . "&fields[1].id=null&fields[1].name=f1name&fields[1].type=f1type";

$resultArray = array();
foreach (explode('&', $query) as $pair) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $pair);

    //a dot present
    if (strpos($key, '.') !== false) {
        list($subKey, $subVal) = explode('.', $key);

        if (preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+)\[(?P<index>\w+)\]/', $subKey, $matches)) {
            $resultArray[$matches['name']][$matches['index']][$subVal] = $value;
        } else {
            $resultArray[$subKey][$subVal] = $value;
        }
    } else {
        $resultArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($resultArray, true) . '</pre>';
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [name] => form1
    [settings] => {"en":{"name":"Form 1","classes":["leftAlign"],"heading":"h2","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[1,0,0]}},"styles":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"}}
    [fields] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => null
                    [name] => password1
                    [type] => Password
                    [settings] => {"en":{"label":"Password 1","value":"","description":"","styles":{"fontFamily":"default","fontSize":"default","fontStyles":[0,0,0]}},"_persistable":true,"required":true,"restriction":"no","styles":{"label":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"value":{"color":"default","backgroundColor":"default"},"description":{"color":"777777","backgroundColor":"default"}}}
                    [sequence] => 0
                    [status] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => null
                    [name] => f1name
                    [type] => f1type
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: how can i group fields[0] & fields[1] values???

Comment: @Parthi04 - see my updated code... Hope this may help you... :)

Comment: Great code... It worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $a = explode('&', $QUERY_STRING); 
 $i = 0; 
 $field = array();
 while ($i < count($a)) {
    $b = split('=', $a[$i]); 
    field[i]= htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[1])); 
    $i++;
 } ?>
```

Comment: @Parthi04 Please accept the answer if this worked for you